# Print Field into Terminal Command

Tags: printing, awk, terminal, arduino

Sorry for confusing you,

well, actually i want to send serial message to my arduino which is connected to /dev/ttyACM0 and it can be done by typing this command into terminal

```
$ echo "Hello Arduino" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

so, i need my awk to send a command just like that.

Here is my PBH.awk file:

```
BEGIN{
    FS = "[ .]";
    RS = "\0";
    IGNORECASE = 1;
}{
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++){
        if(i == 1){
        printf("Diketahui : %s\n",$18);}
        if($i=="y" && $(i+1)=="=")
            {
                printf("     Persamaan : %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",$(i),$(i+1),$(i+2),$(i+3),$(i+4),$(i+5),$(i+6),$(i+7),$(i+8),$(i+9),$(i+10))
                inisialisasi = "stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 cs8 9600 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts"
                kirim = "echo \"Field2 contains: $2""\" > /dev/ttyACM0"
                print | inisialisasi
                print | kirim
            }
    }

}
```

and here is the soalPBH.txt:

```
Persamaan gelombang berjalan pada seutas tali dinyatakan dengan y = 0,02 sin (20 π t – 0,2 π x). Jika x dan y dalam cm dan t dalam sekon, tentukan:
```

Then i run my awk with

```
$ awk -f PBH.awk soalPBH.txt
```

My program doesnt send the text on field number 2.
Is there something wrong with this??

```
kirim = "echo \"Field2 contains: $2""\" > /dev/ttyACM0"
```

Comment: I don't see that you're calling `awk` anywhere in your code. `echo` is a shell command. `print` and `printf("%s...", $1, $2, ...)` are the `awk` methods for writing output. Good luck.

Comment: sorry, i added my full code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its VERY unclear what you're trying to do. Is this it:

```
$ cat file
field1 field2 field3

$ awk '{printf "echo \"Hello Arduino %s\" > /dev/ttyACM0\n", $2}' file
echo "Hello Arduino field2" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

If not, clarify your question and provide some clear sample input and expected output.

Given your updated question, just move the quote so $2 is outside of the quotes instead of inside of them, i.e. `"$2` instead of `$2"`:

```
kirim = "echo \"Field2 contains: " $2 "\" > /dev/ttyACM0"
```

Then tell us if you still have a problem.